# How to rotate a object after the animation is completed using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am trying to rotate a flower after completing the petals.
How do I achieve a slow continuous rotate effect only to the flower?
I have search a lot and all search is resulting to clear the frame and redraw every time.

Below is the code that I have tried.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("flower");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var a = 0,n = 0,r = 0,c = 6;
var x = 0, y = 0;
var w = window.innerWidth, h = window.innerHeight;
var cx = w/2, cy = h/2, rot = 1;

//draw stem
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(cx, h);
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.strokeStyle = "darkgreen";
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(cx+250, cy+100, cx, cy);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.lineWidth = 1;

//start rotating
const startRotate = () =>{
  setInterval(function () {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx, cy);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * (rot += 5));
    ctx.restore(); 
  }, 100);
}

const startDrawing = () =>{
  if(n < 50){   //draw bud
    a =  (n * 137.5)*(180/Math.PI);
    r = c * Math.sqrt(n);
    x = r * Math.cos(a*(180/Math.PI)) + cx;
    y = r * Math.sin(a*(180/Math.PI)) + cy;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "lime";
    ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }else{ //draw petals
    a =  (n * 137.5)*(180/Math.PI);
    r = c * Math.sqrt(n);
    x = r * Math.cos(a*(180/Math.PI)) + cx;
    y = r * Math.sin(a*(180/Math.PI)) + cy;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl('+ a%256 +',100%,50%)';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  n++;
  if(n < 300) requestAnimationFrame(startDrawing);
  else startRotate();
}
startDrawing();
```

```html
<canvas id="flower"></canvas>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would recommend you to do ...
Refactor your code so each circle is an object in a list, then we clear the canvas and re-draw everything on every frame.

See example below:

```js
class circle {
  constructor(n) {
    let a = (n * 137.5) * (180 / Math.PI);
    let r = 6 * Math.sqrt(n);
    this.x = r * Math.cos(a * (180 / Math.PI));
    this.y = r * Math.sin(a * (180 / Math.PI));
    this.radius = 6
    this.id = n
    if (n < 50) {
      this.strokeStyle = "lime";
      this.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    } else {
      this.strokeStyle = "black";
      this.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + a % 256 + ',100%,50%)';
    }
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.strokeStyle;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.fillStyle;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

const canvas = document.getElementById("flower");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
ctx.translate(w / 2, h / 2);
var circles = []
var n = 0;

const startRotate = () => {  
  setInterval(function() {
    ctx.clearRect(-w, -h, w*2, h*2);
    ctx.rotate(0.1)
    circles.forEach(c => { 
      c.draw(ctx);
      if (c.id > 160) {
        c.radius += Math.random() - 0.51;
        c.radius = Math.min(Math.max(c.radius, 2), 10)
      }
    });
  }, 100);
}

const startDrawing = () => {
  circles.push(new circle(n))
  ctx.clearRect(-w, -h, w*2, h*2);
  circles.forEach(c => { c.draw(ctx) });
  n++;
  
  if (n < 300) 
    requestAnimationFrame(startDrawing);
  else 
    startRotate();
}

startDrawing();
```

```html
<canvas id="flower"></canvas>
```

With that in place, now you can control each circle and create more complex animations, like making the flower expand or contract like it opened or closed, or move it up as if it was growing.

Comment: Thank you so much  . Just have a doubt, Is it possible to have the spinning with the stem below? It would be great if the stem was there.

Comment: Sure you can ... but I'm not going to code it for you. that is now homework for you if we do it for you, you would learn nothing

Comment: Thank you, Helder

Comment: You are very welcome @Ashik... I added a bit of a random animation so you can see what can be done with animation